# g++: Can I compile without including Boost if I include a PCH which includes Boost (/seems to include non-PCH)?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, include-path, precompiled-headers

I have the following file, `boost_pch.h`. When compiling, I use `g++ boost_pch.h -I C:\...\boost` which successfully creates the file `boost_pch.h.gch` (g++ 9.2.0).

```cpp
#ifndef BOOST_PCH_H
#define BOOST_PCH_H


#define BOOST_MP_DISABLE_DEPRECATE_03_WARNING

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#endif
```

However, including this in a `.cpp` file and compiling as `g++ my_file.cpp ...` causes an error on the `#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>` ( `fatal error: boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp: No such file or directory`) from `boost_pch.h`. It seems to be including the normal header file and not the PCH.

The first line of the `.cpp` file is

```cpp
#include "boost_pch.h"
```

So is the problem that it's not detecting `boost_pch.h.gch` and trying to include `boost_pch.h` or that I can't precompile a header with additional includes and then expect to be able to include the PCH without adding the required includes?

Running `g++` on `my_file.cpp` with the include path for boost added compiles and works fine, but it takes ages to compile and is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The precompiled header file must be produced for the same language as the current compilation. You cannot use a C precompiled header for a C++ compilation. Try to use the `-x` option to enforce the fact that it is C++ code.